# get and return directories with finder for twig

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm trying to get the directories with finder and return it in twig.
I already got the right directories with finder and do a return in the controller:

```
return $this->render("photos/photos.html.twig",array("Directory"=>$folderFinding));
```

but when i try to get the string in Twig with a foreach:

```
{% for Directories in Directory %}
<p>{{ Directories.directories }}</p>   
{% endfor %}
```

nothing really happens.
Where is my misstake, is it even possible to access it, because i want to use it later?
Here is the dump from twig:

[image: dump]

Comment: You are using wrong references for directory in twig

Comment: oh ok, and what do I have to use?

Comment: Which one references from dump are you need?

Comment: I need the dirs, because i need it later for something like thumbnail for a photo album.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case dirs is an array, so use:

```
{% for Directories in Directory %}
    {% for dir in Directories.dir %}
        <p>{{ dir }}</p>
    {% enfor %}   
{% endfor %}
```

or maybe you Directory is one object, then do:

```
{% for dir in Directory.dirs %}
    <p>{{ dir }}</p>   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, just found the solution